# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object JSON2Apex

Tags: apex, json, error, null-pointer

Having an issue parsing my json using Apex when the value is null. My Json2Apex is being returned like so.

> [object1=cls_object:[amount=11000, amount_refunded=0, application=null, application_fee=null, balance_transaction=txn_1BB1D1Hh4a44STuoX4QnZGfh, captured=true, created=1507555335, currency1=gbp, customer=null, description=Test, destination=null, dispute=null, failure_code=null, failure_message=null, fraud_details=cls_fraud_details:[], id=ch_1BB1D1Hh4a44STuonu0URIAG, invoice=null, livemode=false, metadata=cls_metadata:[], object1=charge, on_behalf_of=null, order=null, outcome=cls_outcome:[network_status=approved_by_network, reason=null, risk_level=normal, seller_message=Payment complete., type=authorized], paid=true, receipt_email=test@testing.com, receipt_number=null, refunded=false, refunds=cls_refunds:[data=(), has_more=false, object1=list, total_count=0, url=/v1/charges/ch_1BB1D1Hh4a44STuonu0URIAG/refunds], review=null, shipping=null, source=cls_source:[address_city=Watton, address_country=GB, address_line1=3 east road, address_line1_check=pass, address_line2=null, address_state=null, address_zip=ip256ay, address_zip_check=pass, brand=Visa, country=US, customer=null, cvc_check=pass, dynamic_last4=null, exp_month=4, exp_year=2021, fingerprint=9riS9I9Iz8qRkF3K, funding=credit, id=card_1BB1CqHh4a44STuo5RG2v7B5, last4=4242, metadata=cls_metadata:[], name=Ben Allington, object1=card, tokenization_method=null], source_transfer=null, statement_descriptor=Test Statement, status=succeeded, transfer_group=null], outcome=null, source=null]

And I am parsing it using the controller class below.

```
public with sharing class StripePaymentController {
//Used to insert Person account from JSON response
public static Account accountInsert(JSON2Apex js) {
    RecordType personAccountRecordType =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Individual Giving - Person Account' and SObjectType = 'Account'];
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.RecordType = personAccountRecordType;
    System.debug(js);
    if(js.source.name!=null){
        acc.name=js.source.name;
        }
    if(js.object1.receipt_email!=null){
        acc.personEmail=js.object1.receipt_email;
        }
    if(js.source.address_city!=null){
        acc.shippingCity=js.source.address_city;
        }
    if(js.source.address_country!=null){
        acc.shippingCountry=js.source.address_country;
        }
    if(js.source.address_zip!=null){
        acc.shippingPostalCode=js.source.address_zip;
        }
    if(js.source.address_line1!=null){
        acc.shippingStreet=js.source.address_line1;
        }
    if(js.source.address_line2!=null){
        acc.shippingStreet=acc.shippingStreet + ',' + js.source.address_line2;
    }

    insert acc;
    return acc; 
}
}
```

But I am getting this error on

> line 8 : System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to parse this checking if the values are null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing null check when you do a dot operator on `source` and `object1` attributes.

You should add a null check before accessing the properties from object. Always keep an eye on line number in debug logs or in error, it helps in debugging when you are not sure.

```
if(js.source != null) {
    if(js.source.name!=null){
        acc.name=js.source.name;
    }
    if(js.source.address_city!=null){
        acc.shippingCity=js.source.address_city;
        }
    if(js.source.address_country!=null){
        acc.shippingCountry=js.source.address_country;
        }
    if(js.source.address_zip!=null){
        acc.shippingPostalCode=js.source.address_zip;
        }
    if(js.source.address_line1!=null){
        acc.shippingStreet=js.source.address_line1;
        }
    if(js.source.address_line2!=null){
        acc.shippingStreet=acc.shippingStreet + ',' + js.source.address_line2;
    }
}

if(js.object1 != null) {
    if(js.object1.receipt_email!=null){
        acc.personEmail=js.object1.receipt_email;
    }
}
```

Before inserting you might want to also add a check if all required fields are populated.

Having a try catch is always good.